# How do I find out what is hammering my SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, performance, cpu-usage

My SQL Server CPU has been at around 90% for the most part of today.

I am not in a position to be able to restart it due to it being in constant use.

Is it possible to find out what within SQL is causing such a CPU overload?

I have run SQL Profiler but so much is going on it's difficult to tell if anything in particular is causing it.

I have run sp_who2 but am not sure what everything means exactly and if it is possible to identify possible problems in here.

To pre-empt any "it's probably just being used a lot" responses, this has only kicked in today from perfectly normal activitly levels.

I'm after any way of finding what is causing CPU grief within SQL.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I assume due diligence here that you confirmed the CPU is actually consumed by SQL process (perfmon Process category counters would confirm this). Normally for such cases you take a sample of the relevant performance counters and you compare them with a baseline that you established in normal load operating conditions. Once you resolve this problem I recommend you do establish such a baseline for future comparisons.

You can find exactly where is SQL spending every single CPU cycle. But knowing where to look takes a lot of know how and experience. Is is SQL 2005/2008 or 2000 ?
Fortunately for 2005 and newer there are a couple of off the shelf solutions. You already got a couple good pointer here with John Samson's answer. I'd like to add a  recommendation to download and install the [SQL Server Performance Dashboard Reports](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=1d3a4a0d-7e0c-4730-8204-e419218c1efc&displaylang=en). Some of those reports include top queries by time or by I/O, most used data files and so on and you can quickly get a feel where the problem is. The output is both numerical and graphical so it is more usefull for a beginner.

I would also recommend using [Adam's Who is Active](http://whoisactive.com/downloads/) script, although that is a bit more advanced.

And last but not least I recommend you download and read the MS SQL Customer Advisory Team white paper on performance analysis: [SQL 2005 Waits and Queues](http://sqlcat.com/whitepapers/archive/2007/11/19/sql-server-2005-waits-and-queues.aspx).

My recommendation is also to look at I/O. If you added a load to the server that trashes the buffer pool (ie. it needs so much data that it evicts the cached data pages from memory) the result would be a significant increase in CPU (sounds surprising, but is true). The culprit is usually a new query that scans a big table end-to-end.

Comment: +1 and you can use this link (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29063) for the newer version of the `SQL Server Performance Dashboard Reports`.

Comment: Would you happen to know why (even) the newest performance dashboard [fails](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/274043/5203) to display the CPU breakdown?

Answer (score 113):

This query uses DMV's to identify the most costly queries by CPU

```
SELECT TOP 20
    qs.sql_handle,
    qs.execution_count,
    qs.total_worker_time AS Total_CPU,
    total_CPU_inSeconds = --Converted from microseconds
        qs.total_worker_time/1000000,
    average_CPU_inSeconds = --Converted from microseconds
        (qs.total_worker_time/1000000) / qs.execution_count,
    qs.total_elapsed_time,
    total_elapsed_time_inSeconds = --Converted from microseconds
        qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000,
    st.text,
    qp.query_plan
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS st
CROSS APPLY
    sys.dm_exec_query_plan (qs.plan_handle) AS qp
ORDER BY 
    qs.total_worker_time DESC
```

For a complete explanation see: [How to identify the most costly SQL Server queries by CPU](http://www.johnsansom.com/how-to-identify-the-most-costly-sql-server-queries-using-dmvs/)

Comment: What if it's system related: VLFs, checkpointing, stats rebuilds etc

Comment: Most useful piece of SQL i have used in a long time. Saved my butt. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can find some useful query here:

[Investigating the Cause of SQL Server High CPU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/docast/2017/07/30/sql-high-cpu-troubleshooting-checklist/)

For me this helped a lot:

```
SELECT s.session_id,
    r.status,
    r.blocking_session_id 'Blk by',
    r.wait_type,
    wait_resource,
    r.wait_time / (1000 * 60) 'Wait M',
    r.cpu_time,
    r.logical_reads,
    r.reads,
    r.writes,
    r.total_elapsed_time / (1000 * 60) 'Elaps M',
    Substring(st.TEXT,(r.statement_start_offset / 2) + 1,
    ((CASE r.statement_end_offset
WHEN -1
THEN Datalength(st.TEXT)
ELSE r.statement_end_offset
END - r.statement_start_offset) / 2) + 1) AS statement_text,
    Coalesce(Quotename(Db_name(st.dbid)) + N'.' + Quotename(Object_schema_name(st.objectid, st.dbid)) + N'.' +
    Quotename(Object_name(st.objectid, st.dbid)), '') AS command_text,
    r.command,
    s.login_name,
    s.host_name,
    s.program_name,
    s.last_request_end_time,
    s.login_time,
    r.open_transaction_count
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s
    JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests AS r
ON r.session_id = s.session_id
    CROSS APPLY sys.Dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) AS st
WHERE r.session_id != @@SPID
ORDER BY r.cpu_time desc
```

In the fields of `status`, `wait_type` and `cpu_time` you can find the most CPU consuming task that is running right now.

Comment: @GrahamH I like to have things clear and nice. Formatted text is nice text.

Comment: nothing was needed.............sad

Answer (score 7):

Run either of these a few second apart. You'll detect the high CPU connection.
Or: stored CPU in a local variable, WAITFOR DELAY, compare stored and current CPU values

```
select * from master..sysprocesses
where status = 'runnable' --comment this out
order by CPU
desc

select * from master..sysprocesses
order by CPU
desc
```

May not be the most elegant but it'd effective and quick.

Comment: Hi thanks for that, I did that and it came back with LOGMGR_QUEUE cpu column being at 20296. What unit is this figure in?

Answer (score 7):

You can run the SQL Profiler, and filter by CPU or Duration so that you're excluding all the "small stuff". Then it should be a lot easier to determine if you have a problem like a specific stored proc that is running much longer than it should (could be a missing index or something).

Two caveats:

- If the problem is massive amounts of tiny transactions, then the filter I describe above would exclude them, and you'd miss this.
- Also, if the problem is a single, massive job (like an 8-hour analysis job or a poorly designed select that has to cross-join a billion rows) then you might not see this in the profiler until it is completely done, depending on what events you're profiling (sp:completed vs sp:statementcompleted).

But normally I start with the Activity Monitor or sp_who2.

Answer (score 3):

For a GUI approach I would take a look at Activity Monitor under Management and sort by CPU.

Comment: Hopefully the GUI won't time out with the "lock timeout" error that happens on loaded SQL Server boxes...

Comment: For sure, but I suggested it because I have experienced the following
Random Character: CPU critical!!!!!
Me: Sounds like a job for system tables! <writing query furiously>
Not Me: Don't worry about it, I found and killed the culprit in Activity Monitor.

Comment: A stored procedure that generated data for a report. Lots of joins and aggregates, fragmented indexes. We re-wrote the query using with (nolock and rebuilt all the indexes and it stopped being a problem.