# How to find the SQL query of a sql hande on amazon RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I use an amazon RDS SQL Server 2012 medium instance.

I used a query found here:
[How do I find out what is hammering my SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945063/how-do-i-find-out-what-is-hammering-my-sql-server)
to find an sql handle of a query that is taking up far more time than anything else.

I tried using sys.fn_get_sql with the sql handle that the query above retuned, but select is denied with my amazon RDS user.

Is there a way I can find out what the query is while on amazon RDS?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way I know of to run that system function against the server. As an alternative, you could use SQL Server Profiler to connect to your instance and set a filter on the SPID you found in your query results.

Detailed instructions on how to hookup Profiler can be found in the Amazon RDS User guide, specifically in the [Common DBA Tasks for Microsoft SQL Server Appendix](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.html).